# Convert sql query to Hql query

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

please can someone help convert this sql query to an Hql query. Or can the query run as Hql?

```
select p.passport_data, b.unique_number, d.da38 as category
from passport p, dynamic_data d, basic_data b
where b.id = d.basic_data_fk
and p.basic_data_fk = b.id and d.da38 = 'SUBEB'
```

they entity classes are: Passport, BasicData, DynamicData

```
Passport entity class has fields/variables- passportData, basicData
BasicData entity class has fields/variables- id, uniqueNumber
DynamicData entity class has fields/variables- da38
```

Comment: You have to show us, how tables passport, dynamic_data and basic_data are mapped to hibernate entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select p.passport_data, b.unique_number, d.da38 as category
from Passport p, DynamicData d, BasicData b
where b.id = d.basicData
and p.basicData = b.id and d.da38 = 'SUBEB'
```

I suppose in your DynamicData exists a field named basicData (as in Passport class)